# Python BeautifulSoup - find table by id returning 'none'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

For some reason I can't find a table by id or select the table by id.. I've been referring to the docs for BS and from what I can tell it should be working..

Below is an example of the code to try and select the table by the id "per_game", content.find(id='per_game') doesn't work for me either.

I've been referring to the find and CSS selector part of the docs, here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find

```
import requests
import csv
import calendar
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

season = str(date.today().year + 1)
month = calendar.month_name[date.today().month].lower()

teamUrl = "https://basketball-reference.com/teams/"

urls       =    [teamUrl + 'ATL/' + season +'.html'] # Atlanta Hawks
                 # teamUrl + 'BOS/' + season +'.html', # Boston Celtics
                 # teamUrl + 'BKN/' + season +'.html', # Brooklyn Nets
                 # teamUrl + 'CHA/' + season +'.html', # Charlotte Hornets

for url in urls:
    page = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    content = soup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    table = content.select("#per_game")
    print(table)
```

Many thanks,
OM.

Comment: That content is built client-side using JavaScript, so your code won't see it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43120445/scraping-a-webpage-that-has-javascript-with-beautifulsoup

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python

Comment: You need to use some module which can run JavaScript, then you can load all the data. btw i ever answer a question like this one (same website but he want to scrape the records of each player)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BS4 Not Locating Element in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53110585/bs4-not-locating-element-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not Ajax, just remove comment from the html

```
page = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html_doc = page.text.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '')
content = soup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
```